# Symmetric Key Decryption returning values with space between characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption-symmetric

I am using following Scaler-valued function to decrypt data that is encrypted using a symmetric key:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DECRYPTDATA] 
(
    @CipherText NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @Result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DECRYPTBYKEY(@CipherText))
    RETURN @Result
END
```

And I am using following query to get the data:

```
EXEC [dbo].OpenKeys
SELECT ([dbo].DECRYPTDATA([Value])) AS VALUE FROM [Table1] WHERE [UsrId] =2 AND [GroupID] = 44
```

I executed this query in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, it's showing only the first letter of the decrypted text:

[image]

And when I checked the `DataTable` in C# code, it's showing space between characters:

[image]

Actual data must be like this:

```
╔═══════╗
║ VALUE ║
╠═══════╣
║ 232   ║
║ hgjhg ║
║ 12    ║
║ 53    ║
║ 0     ║
╚═══════╝
```

What's happening here?

**UPDATE**

I tried inserting directly like `INSERT INTO Table1([Value]) VALUES([dbo].ENCRYPTISDATA('432'))` but when I fetch this row it shows `4` only. So I think the problem is at the SQL Server side. What it is I don't know. Hope somebody can figure out soon. I have to submit this project in some days.

**I am using TripleDES algorithm.**

Comment: It may or may not be the issue, but your function has a couple of code smells to me. 1) `decryptbykey` takes a varbinary as the ciphertext, not an nvarchar. 2) you're converting to varchar but returning nvarchar. What data type was the original plaintext? As for your latest comment, try using the raw `encryptbykey` call or post the code for your ENCRYPTISDATA function.

Comment: I agree with @BenThul. Please provide more details. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you so much @BenThul . Your hint helped me trace the problem cause. I checked all the Stored Procedures and functions that are being called before the encryption and decryption. I found that both of your possibilities were true. At one place I forgot to convert to `varbinary` and at other I was storing the result of decryption in a `nvarchar`. I changed everything to `nvarchar` (since it's better than `varchar`) and it worked. Thanks a lot. If you wish you can add it as your answer. I will mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there are a couple of things at play here:

1. `decryptbykey` takes a varbinary, not an nvarchar. I'd guess that there is some unwanted conversion going on there.
2. You're converting the result of the decryption to varchar but returning from your function as nvarchar. Again unwanted conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the underlying cause of this issue, in case your original data does not contain blank spaces between characters, then you can apply a quick fix like: `strWithSpaces=strWithSpaces.Replace(" ", String.Empty);`

In regards to the cause: your original string before encryption probably contains some non-printable (i.e. invisible) characters, which get encoded. I recommend to analyze the original data prior to encryption, and remove the unnecessary `chars` at that stage using similar technique.

Hope this may help.

Comment: It may contain spaces because it stores string values and they can be anything like user's full name or address, which can contain spaces.

Comment: I've extended the answer. Please run the test and include samples of original data prior to encoding. Best regards,

Comment: I tried inserting directly like `INSERT INTO Table1([Value]) 
                     VALUES([dbo].ENCRYPTISDATA('432'))` but when I fetch this row it shows `4` only.